# PostgreSQL "&" symbol and number after column name

Tags: database, psql

I have psql version 9.2.4.
I am vivewing log file of our database and i found something weird for me.
There are WHERE statements where:

```
te_flag&1024 = 0
te_flag&5120 <> 1024
```

I don't know what part "&1024" after column name does.
Can someone explain it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `&` is the [bitwise and operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-math.html). E.g.:

```
db=> SELECT 4 & 2 AS bitwise_4_and_2;
 bitwise_4_and_2 
-----------------
               0
(1 row)
```

Comment: So statement: "te_flag&1024" is bitwise and of column "te_flag" and 1024?

Comment: @Blejwi yes, exactly.